# Grammaticality of "have we gotta have"

Tags: grammaticality, have-got

I've read a sentence that sounded a bit strange, and one that could be wrong:
In his book *All Our To-morrows* (1942), Douglas Reed says:

> "Say, ***have we gotta have*** any coupons for chicken or rabbits?"

He was reporting Canadian soldier's speech.

Is this form *have we gotta have* a valid form or is it just a typo?
Thank you so much.

Comment: Seems perfectly ok as colloquial English, if "have we gotta" is being used in the sense *do we have to* = *must we*. E.g. "Hey, have we gotta have a debate on this? Can't we just agree?" But it's not clear from the context if that's what it's being used for. Please add more detail.

Comment: It's colloquial speech, not much different from what you might hear in many parts of the US.

Comment: Generally: Gotta = got to. I think the writer is just giving you a feel for the characters accent. I would say it was fairly common in the UK, most people listening to me in a casual conversation might write it down as *gotta* and I have a very BBC English accent. E.g. Gotta run, catch you later.

Comment: I am not accustomed to the Canadian dialect, but still believe that it means "must." thank you.

Comment: The character is basically asking "do we need" (any coupons).

Comment: "Have we got to go to school next Thursday?" would be unremarkable in the UK. I disagree with @Bee when he rather disingenuously implies that "Have we gotta go to school next Thursday?" would be the preferred way of recording this among people using 'standard English'. But in slang and perhaps accepted informal registers in the UK, and certainly in the US and probably in Canada, it would be considered acceptable in all but the most formal of registers.

Comment: @Edwin, I didn't say prefered, I said it would make sense. Clearly it's not something you'd use in a formal setting. I wouldn't be surprised to hear someone concatenate the two words. The only place, as I mentioned, I would expect it written is when the writer is trying to convey a dialect of some kind. Also - she 

Comment: Note: "Old English" means English as she was spoke before 1066 or so.  Think Beowulf.  (Hƿæt! ƿē Gār-Dena in ġeār-dagum)  Anyway, this question is not on Old English.

Comment: @Bee  "I would say it was fairly common in the UK[;] most people listening to me in a casual conversation might write it down as 'gotta' and I have a very BBC English accent." _I have a very BBC English accent_ rather strongly suggests that most people listening to you in a casual conversation would have that accent, and  that 'gotta' is thus the preferred (>50%) way of recording this among such people. I'd guess that many people even in the UK use 'gotta' quite a lot when texting, but I'd hold out that 'have got to' is more acceptable in formal UK English (hence I'm stressing the point).

Comment: @Edwin, Saying I think it's common in speech is very different to me saying that it's preferred in, say, an essay. I believe it is used very regularly in everyday speech and, as you pointed out, texting. I never, however, meant to imply that I think it would be used in formal writing except where the author might be trying to convey a certain accent. Apologies if you miss interpreted me. I'd also like to point out that the "BBC English" accent it's >50% of the population. I'd say regional dialects seem far more common.

Answer (score 4):

Margery Fee & Janice McAlpine, *Oxford Guide to Canadian English Usage*, second edition (2007) has this entry on Canadian use of "have got to":

> **have got to** Commentators have condemned the use of *have got to* meaning be compelled to, recommending *must* or *have to* instead: that is, 'I must (*or* have to) go' rather than 'I have got to go'. However, *Webster's Dictionary of English Usage* notes that Otto Jesperson collected many examples of *have got to* from a range of important British writers, among them Dickens, Trollope, and Shaw, and its authors ad a list of their own that includes William Faulkner and several American presidents. In other words, it is not necessary to avoid *have got to*.

This assessment of "have got to" basically gives the wording a green light. But two other elements of the sentence "Say, have we gotta have any coupons for chicken or rabbits?" remain to be explored: the use of "gotta" for "got to," and the use of *have* as the infinitive at the end of a phrase that also begins with *have*.

The contracted form *gotta* is sufficiently informal that *Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary* (2003) declines to provide an entry for it. *The American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language*, fifth edition (2010), however, steps up with this entry:

> **gotta** *Informal* Contraction of *got to*: *I gotta go home*.

The form *gotta* owes its existence to attempts by writers to approximate the pronunciation of "got to" used by many native English speakers in North America (and perhaps elsewhere). But clearly the word doesn't raise any grammatical problems that "got to" does not.

As for the second *have* in "have we gotta have," it may sound odd in this construction, but it is present in many declarative (as opposed to interrogative) constructions of the same basic syntactical form such as "you've gotta have a license" and "I've gotta have something to eat." And the awkwardness of "have we gotta have" is hardly improved by swapping in "have to" for "have got to" in the quotation: "Say, have we to have any coupons for chicken or rabbits?" (Even "Say, must we have any coupons for chicken or rabbits?" sounds a bit weird, owing partly to the mismatch in register between "Say" [in the sense of "Hey, wait a minute"] and "must we" [in a sentence position where "do we have to" would be the most likely choice in informal spoken North American English] and partly to the clunkiness of "must" and "any" in the sentence; once *must* enters the picture, *some* seems a better modifier than *any* for *coupons*, although the sentence would sound even more natural without any modifier: "Must we have coupons for chicken or rabbits?")

If I were composing the quoted sentence, and I chose to start it with "Say" and to include "gotta" part of the way through it, I would be strongly tempted to replace the first "have" with "do," to maintain the speaker's diction at a consistent level:

> "Say, do we gotta have any coupons for chicken or rabbits?"

But the author may have blanched at the prospect of having even a character prone to using informal speech patterns and forms say "do we got to."

If, on the other hand, I didn't want the speaker to sound indifferent to educated syntactical norms, I would probably have worded the sentence this way:

> "Say, do we need to have coupons for chicken or rabbits?"

But the author's version of the quotation is grammatically and syntactically defensible—and it is certainly possible that someone—Canadian or not—might actually say those words rather than the ones I would have chosen.

Comment: +1  "Do we gotta..."